# How do you select the IOS simulator as a target in Instruments?

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, instruments

I am new to IOS app development...

How do I select the IOS Simulator as a target from the Instruments application, so I can debug/profile an IOS App running on the simulator.

In Instruments I select:
   File -> New
   then pick the IOS Simulator / Memory / Allocations 'template', click 'choose'

Under 'Choose Target' the only existing targets show are my Macbook and a real iPod device.
How do I select the IOS Simulator as a target??
If I select the 'Choose Target' option Instruments brings up a dialog where it wants me to select something from my filesystem... have no idea what to select.

This is Instruments 4.2.

Also, contrary to a various bits of info on the web, I can see no way to launch Instruments from in Xcode 4.2.

Thanks.

Comment: If you click and hold on the run button, it turns into 4 other options.  Click profile.

Answer (score 13):

You can launch Instruments directly from Xcode. Just choose the iOS Simulator as your build scheme and choose Profile from the Product menu.

Comment: Cmd + I .// That is 'I' for Instruments.

Answer (score 8):

@CodaFi's comment above helped me figure out the solution.

Click and hold the run button in XCode or click on the little expansion triangle.
Next choose Profile, which will open instruments and allow you to choose what you would like to profile :-)

I hope this helps!